# Separate digits AB to A and B inside df pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with some data placed in some bytes. I have the problem that inside the frame there are two bits reserved for a toggle function that does not matter to me, but its affecting the final result of my task.

The byte frame looks like this:

```
Start bit  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
    0      A A A A A A A A 
    8      A A 
   16      B B B B B B B B   
   24      B B         C C

C represents the toggle
```

My df looks like this:

```
A   A   B   B
BA  00  11  02
BA  00  11  02
BA  00  11  42
BA  00  11  42
BA  00  11  82
BA  00  11  82
BA  00  11  C2
BA  00  11  C2
BA  00  11  02
BA  00  11  02
```

I can see that from B the 1st part of the second Byte is cycling, meaning that the 2nd digit is the toggle. I guess or am I wrong? Afterward, this digit (2) changes in my df for 1 & then 0.

Is there a way that I can convert, separate or eliminate the 2nd digit or a way to only take the 1st digit (this case 0). eg. 02 --> 0 and 2 just take the 0. My df afterward is a different number than 0 but the 0,4,8 and C is continuos regardless and the 2 also changes later to 1 and then 0. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that look for an answer I consulted with my pillow and we agreed to try the following that actually it worked:

So after putting together the bytes like this:

```
df['A'] = df.iloc[:,1] + '' + df.iloc[:,0]    #Dominant byte is the second position
df['B'] = df.iloc[:,3] + '' + df.iloc[:,2]
```

Output:

```
  A       B
00BA    0211  
00BA    0211  
00BA    4211  
00BA    4211  
00BA    8211  
00BA    8211  
00BA    C211  
00BA    C211  
00BA    0211  
00BA    0211
```

I did the following:

```
df['B'] = df['B'].str[1:] #Only take the last three digits of the array
```

Output:

```
 A       B
00BA    211  
00BA    211  
00BA    211  
00BA    211  
00BA    211  
00BA    211  
00BA    211  
00BA    211  
00BA    211  
00BA    211
```